# Hibernate executing queries sequentially

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, nativequery

I am using query variables in my hibernate native mysql query.for every execution i should set my query variable as 0.

for that i am executing another query like

> SET @var:=0.

But spring make things asynchronous.It executes another query after set the variable.so the results are not as expected.

I have  header and items tables.every header has multiple items.

**Example**

> header = {h1,h2,h3},
>
> items={i1,i2,i3,i4,i5,i6,i7,i8}
>
> h1->{i1,i2,i3},h2->{i4,i5},h3->{i6,i7,i8}

i want result like

> row1 : h1,i1
>
> row2: h1,i2
>
> row3:h1,i3
>
> and so on..

we can use joins here.but in my case i fetch the results as paginations.

like first 1 to 10 headers(with items) in first page,1 to 20 in 2nd page ..

if i use joins with **limit** keyword we get desired records.

but here i want number of headers for per page.

thats why i am using query variable @cnt for counting headers.

the query is :

> `SET @cnt:=0;`
>
> `SELECT pk_header_id,
>       pk_item_id,
>       @cnt := IF( @header_id is not null AND @header_id != pk_header_id,
>           @cnt := @cnt + 1,
>           @cnt) AS cnt,
>       @header_id:=pk_header_id
>    FROM header join item on fk_header_id = pk_header_id order by pk_header_id.`

For every execution the @cnt variable is increased to 10 and i should make it as 0 for every query execution.

Comment: why every beginners use native sql query in JPA? With updates ... terrible

Comment: I should use native sql in my case.no alternative

Comment: Why can you not define your native query as something like `SELECT * FROM TheTable WHERE field = ?` and then call `#setParameter( 0, yourValue )` ?  Is there a particular reason why you need to do it the way you illustrate?  You haven't given sufficient information to indicate why you're taking this path in the first place.

Comment: Updated question with details.